# phpmyadmin can't connect to external server on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, database, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I got `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when I tried to connect phpmyadmin to mariadb on an external server seeing `http://192.168.10.165/phpmyadmin`.

[image]

Here is the list of server.

- masterDB(192.168.10.165)
- maxscale(192.168.10.175)
- phpmyadmin(192.168.10.185)

This is the setting of [/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php]

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test123';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
```

Here are some setting of mariadb and maxscale

mariadb

```
[mysqld]

pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
proxy_protocol_networks = 192.168.10.175/24, localhost
server-id  =  1
max_connections        = 5000
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

grants for phpmyadmin

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for phpmyadmin@192.168.10.185                                                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `phpmyadmin`@`192.168.10.185` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*9678F24DBDAFA9F106368B335C371B581501E926' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

maxscale

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
log_info=true
log_warn_super_user=true
syslog=true
maxlog=true

[MariaDB-Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mariadbmon
servers=masterDB, replicaDB1, replicaDB2
user=monitor
password=test123
monitor_interval=2s

[masterDB]
type=server
address=192.168.10.165
port=3306
protocol=MariaDBBackend
proxy_protocol=true
monitoruser=monitor
monitorpw=test123
persistpoolmax=5000
max_routing_connections=3000
persistmaxtime=3600s

[Write-Service]
type=service
router=readconnroute
router_options=master, slave
servers=masterDB
user=maxscale
password=test123
idle_session_pool_time=15s
multiplex_timeout=40s
max_connections=2000

[Write-Listener]
type=listener
service=Write-Service
protocol=MariaDBClient
port=3309
address=0.0.0.0
```

I changed `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.175:3309';` because I thought the parameter "proxy_protocol_networks" caused this problem, but I saw same result like a picture I put above.
I got `NOT FOUND` error when I saw `http://192.168.10.185/phpmyadmin`

I'd like to know

- How to solve `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
- Is it possible that the parameter "proxy_protocol_networks" causes
  this error.

Could anyone help me, please?

---

Thank you so much for everything you've taught me.
I found the causes of this error. They are 2 reasons below.

- Wrong URL (the right URL was `http://192.168.10.185/phpmyadmin`)
- Wrong setting in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` (I fixed some values of parameters what I added and also changed values of parameters that are configured from the beginning)

I hope this picture below is helpful to understand what I did in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

[setting of /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVY0l.png)

Comment: You didn't tell us what the actual error is

Comment: Is this a programming related problem after all? Did you write any code on your own? Or is this about configuring phpMyAdmin or MariaDB properly?

Comment: @NicoHaase people _are_ allowed to ask questions about software tools commonly used by programmers (as per the [help/on-topic]), it doesn't necessarily have to be about programming in the most literal sense

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ADyson. And I'm sorry about it. I added extra information here. If it's not enough information, please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of information about the problem.  I think this error has been caused by my wrong setting. I added extra information about setting of MariaDB. As for phpMyAdmin, I haven't touched any files other than `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`  and I'm probably wrong there. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Ok. So from what I can work out, the phpmyadmin application is installed on the `phpmyadmin(192.168.10.185)` server, and mariadb is installed on the `masterDB(192.168.10.165)`. From what I can tell, the proxy server setting isn't really playing a part (but you could try just removing the `proxy_protocol_networks` setting temporarily, to be sure). So if that's all correct, then it's clear that trying `http://192.168.10.165/phpmyadmin` makes no sense because phpmyadmin isn't installed on that server - it probably doesn't even have a webserver either, hence why you can't connect that way

Comment: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.175:3309';` also doesn't seem to make sense, because mariadb isn't installed on that server. I don't think that's a helpful change. `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';` looks like it was probably right. And anyway this isn't related to the errors you're seeing - those errors are about your browser trying to connect to phpmyadmin, whereas this config setting is about how phpmyadmin connects to mariadb. Clearly those are two independent things.

Comment: `ttp://192.168.10.185/phpmyadmin` makes more sense as an address to try and locate phpmyadmin in your browser. If you're getting a NOT FOUND for that, it suggests the webserver is running, but that phpmyadmin isn't set up at that specific URL. Without seeing how the webserver is configured we can't really tell you what the correct URL should be on that server, though

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, ADyson. I could solve this error and the 2 causes of it were exactly what you corrected. Those were wrong URL and wrong setting in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. The right URL was `http://192.168.10.185/phpmyadmin`. As for the configure file, `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';` was correct and I needed to change `  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']`.  I added a picture of the parameters of theconfigure file, so I hope it help you to get what I did in the file.

Comment: Additionally, as for `proxy_protocol_networks` didn't matter this error.
I appreciate your all kindness and help.

Comment: Glad we fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Once you've added an answer properly, you should also roll back the edit to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wrong URL (the right URL was http://192.168.10.185/phpmyadmin)
- Wrong setting in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php (I fixed some values of parameters what I added and also changed values of parameters that are configured from the beginning)

```
$i++;　　

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';　　
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';　　
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'phpmyadmin';　　
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'test123';　


if (!empty($dbname)) {
    /* Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = '192.168.10.165';　　# here！ 
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.10.165';　　　# here！

    if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != 'localhost') {
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
    }
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
    /* Optional: User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'phpmyadmin';　　　　# here！
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'test123';　　　　# here！
```